# Plot word count on x axis and its occurrence on y axis from pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

The goal is to plot something like this:

[image: plot]

I have the following dummy df.
Note that data = number of words = x axis

```
data = [13,2,2,13,14,5,6,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,200,12,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,4,5,5,6,7,3,2,3,4,6,5,4,7,4,7,4,7,1,1,32,7,9,4,6,2,2,3,2,1,1]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['number_of_words'])
```

Now I need to calculate the y-axis, namely the occurrences of the number of words. E.g. How often is number of words = 1 and how often = 9 and so on...
I did it this way:

```
data = my_df['number_of_words'].value_counts()
```

Then I created a new df with that:

```
df_occurrences = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df_occurrences.rename(columns={"number_of_words": "occurrences"}, inplace=True)
```

Now I wanted to merge them but their length is different because `my_df` includes duplicates.

Thus, I removed the duplicates.

```
my_df.drop_duplicates(subset ="number_of_words", keep=False, inplace=True)
```

`my_df` and `df_occurrences` now have a different length and I cannot merge and plot them anymore...

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: `df['occurrences'] = df['number_of_words'].map(df['number_of_words']).value_counts())`.

Comment: Are you actually looking for something like `my_df.value_counts().sort_index().plot()`?

Comment: `[{"number_of_words": v, "occurrences": data.count(v)} for v in set(data)]`

Comment: @BigBen oh my, didn't think about that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user BigBen wrote in the comment to the original question post, `my_df.value_counts().sort_index().plot()` is all I needed to do. The other approaches mentioned by Quang Hoang and keithpjolley in the same comment section also work.

Answer (score 1):

I used set and count method. The loop iterate over set(data) and count method count the number of occurrences of an item in the list. I use the sorted function . b is the zero item and c is the first item in the nested list. b is x-axis and c is y-axis in plot.

```
d = sorted([[x,data.count(x)] for x in set(data)])
b = []
c = []
for i,j in d:
   b.append(i)
   c.append(j)
plt.plot(b,c)
```